# BPEL process execution and input elements

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I Have a BPEL process taking 3 inputs and (name,age,country) all are string type. while invoking this BPEL process I am passing only two parameters. 
On Assign Activity I am copying these variabled to BPEL variables. at that time  the result is leading to SelectionFailure Exception.

for this I tried Scope and keep my Assign Activity in that and added a CatchAll Block. In catch block I kept one more assign Activity. but there I can not decide which field is blank.

second I tried nillable="true" (I am not sure this is working or not) .

Both of the way not worked,

Answer (score 0):

try to initiate to empty value the three variables to avoid the exception and its treatment

```
   <copy>
       <from>
           <literal>
               <ns0:variable1>
                    <ns0:element</ns0:element>
                    </ns0:variable1>
                </literal>
            </from>
            <to variable="variable1" part="partOfMessage"/>
        </copy>

        <copy>
            <from>
                <literal>
                    <ns0:variable2>
                        <ns0:element</ns0:element>
                    </ns0:variable2>
                </literal>
            </from>
            <to variable="variable2" part="partOfMessage"/>
        </copy>
```

Comment: Thanks, My problem I have explained in this link too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580029/how-to-handle-bpel-fault/6584554#6584554