# How to handle BPEL fault

Tags: soa, bpel

How to handle fault in BPEL (SOA 11.1.1.4). I have a BPEL process the inputs are as 3 Strings input and one Array of a Employee class.

Now I want to put validation as inputs can not be null.
then how to do fault handling for this.
everytime  i am facing Selection failure Exception.

One way to achieve this I should the validation before invoking the BPEL.

how i can handle this inside the process.

I am using SOA 11.1.1.4 and JDeveloper 11.1.1.4

Answer (score 1):

You don't state if you are using BPEL 1.1 or BPEL 2.0 processes.  In BPEL 1.1 adding an exception handler for the SelectionFailure exception will work.

In BPEL 2.0 you need to add a catch all as there appears to be a bug in the handling of specific faults.

If you also are using Oracles BPEL Fault Management framework then you need to add a new test condition for selectionfailure errors and have it's action method execute an ora-rethrow action for this particular error

Comment: Thanks, I am using BPEL 2.0. I checked with scope activity, and catch All. then I was able to run my process. but I did not find any place where I will hook my validation program that will check all validation and return the exception to calling program.

Comment: You could do it within the scope, but if it is a case of determing what field is invalid then the logical place would be to do it in the catchall as you then know it is an error and you can determine what fields are at fault without explicitly copying them

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could modify the wsdl so that the XML won't permit nulls and then turn on schema validation.

If you want to handle it inside the process, check it with an assign and use a catch block on the scope to trap the error and set the parameters for a wsdl fault.